# TestFlight and push notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, onesignal

When I install my app using Xcode by plugging in my iPhone to my Mac and running the project I get notifications. When I upload it to TestFlight and then I go on the TestFlight version I won't get notifications from my app.

I honesty believe I'm doing something wrong with my entitlements or distribution profile.

I'm using onesignal for my notifications

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information to help you. Let's see some code, configuration profiles, something!

Comment: I just would like a step by step instructions

Comment: Go to developer.apple.com, go to certificates section, and make sure that Push Notifications are enabled for the bundle id that you are using in test flight.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, about the more strict of voters.

When you're working with "push notifications" they only work on an actual device.. NOT on the simulator..

So when you're device is plugged in the "UUID that iOS sends back to Apple with the Push Notification details gets sent".

When you're using the simulator, then you don't have any push notifications or (APNS notifications).

So ideally develop in the simulator, and post an "NSLog (debugLog etc..)" in simulator, and when you're back on your device being plugged in , then you can use push again.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is due to the 2 APNS environments. The first environment is sandbox, which is when you are developing the on your phone. You seem to have that working. The next is production, which even though Testflight is for testing, it still uses the production level APNS environment. Check your provisioning profiles and ensure you have the proper certificates for production level APNS. Once you do, you should see your push notifications come in for your TestFlight builds.